# How to execute op level commands for non-op players with command signs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

After learning how to make signs that run commands when you click them, I have relied on them a lot with my Minecraft server.  Most of the teleporting stuff and `/say` stuff use them. They were working for me and the other admins but when a non-OP player tries them, she said they weren't doing anything. Is there any way to fix this or will I just have to switch everything to pressure plates? On other servers that I've played on, teleporting signs work for non-OP players but I assume this is just some plugin.

I've looked up how to give non-op players permissions and how to make non-op players able to use teleporting signs. I found nothing useful. For both, I only found stuff about plugins which is something the other admin and I are struggling to get. Do you know how to do this WITHOUT plugins or are plugins required?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Really. This comment again!? I'm not stuck, I just have a question

Comment: And again, *what have you tried?*  You showing effort goes an extremely long way here.

Comment: Is it a vanilla server? Other servers might use CommandSigns or similar.

Comment: Yes, it is a vanilla server. Sorry Frank, I really don't even know how to start to figure it out and I can't find anything useful on the internet.

Comment: Showing us your research is still good, even if you didn't find exactly what you're looking for. Then we at least see you're trying to figure this out on your own.

Comment: Ok, I added a research section to the Question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In vanilla minecraft, the use of [scoreboard triggers](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria) can allow non OP players to [trigger](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#trigger) the execution of op level commands.  Commands are Minecraft Java Edition is 1.12.2

#### Setup

Create a trigger objective one time manually:

```
scoreboard objectives add cmdTrigger trigger
```

Next you have to enable that trigger to allow players to use it.  Create a command block and set it's options to <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players enable @a cmdTrigger
```

#### Command Setup

Now create a chain of two command blocks.  This chain will need to be repeated for each command that you want non OP players to run but the scores in the commands will be different.

The first command block is where the OP level command is executed on the behalf of the player.  This is accomplished by specifying the cmdTrigger score in the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).  An example target selector is `@a[score_cmdTrigger_min=1,score_cmdTrigger=1]`.  The first command block needs to check continuously so it is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd>

Some example commands are:

- Teleport the player somewhere:

  - `tp @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=1,score_cmdTrigger=1] <x> <y> <z>`
- Make the player say hello:

  - `execute @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=1,score_cmdTrigger=1] ~ ~ ~ say Hello`

The second command block resets the cmdTrigger score back to 0 so it will only execute the previous command one time.  It is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Conditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players set @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=1,score_cmdTrigger=1] cmdTrigger 0
```

Use different cmdTrigger scores to trigger different commands.  A second set of commands would use target selector:

```
@a[score_cmdTrigger_min=2,score_cmdTrigger=2]
```

Continue with as many chains as you want commands.

#### Command the player needs to execute

The actual command the player has to execute in order to trigger the OP level command:

```
/trigger cmdTrigger set <score>
```

Set the `<score>` based on the command that you want to execute.  The player can manually enter this command in chat and it will succeed.  This requires they know what command to type and what each score does.

In your case, this is where you use the command signs to run the trigger commands.  You can use this [Command Sign Generator](https://minecraftcommand.science/command-sign-generator) to create these signs more easily.  Here is an example command that will give you a sign that when placed and clicked, will trigger the first command you have setup:

```
/give @p sign 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Text1:"{\"text\":\"Run the\"}",Text2:"{\"text\":\"first command\"}",Text4:"{\"text\":\"Click the sign\",\"color\":\"aqua\",\"clickEvent\":{\"action\":\"run_command\",\"value\":\"/trigger cmdTrigger set 1\"}}"},display:{Name:"Example Sign"}}
```

Comment: BTW, I already use that generator, but thanks

Comment: No problem.  I mention the generator just in case.  No need to thank me.  In fact, stack exchange would rather you didn't use comments to say thank you.  It's all covered in the help center on the page "[What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)".

Comment: okay, got it. This is very complicated but I think I can figure it out

Comment: Do you discord?  I can hop on your server and help.

Comment: what's discord?

Comment: Our server has a whitelist because it was recently attacked by a hacker. I can contact my fellow admin to see if he can whitelist you for a bit so you can help. I'll get back to you in 5-30 mins. He may not respond for a bit. What's ur minecraft username?

Comment: If he doesn't whitelist you, I'll realm invite you and I can backpack the needed command blocks

Comment: Discord is a gamers chat program, kind of like skype. My Minecraft username is IronAnvil.

Comment: The other admin isn't availible, so do u wanna come to my realm? I invited you so you could show me there

Comment: This isn't working now for some reason. I just copied the command blocks from the realm and brought them to the server but they won't work

Comment: I would read through my answer carefully.  When I built the system on your realm, I just copied and pasted from my answer.