# How Do You Make Scoreboard Triggers Teleport People?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With the help of IronAnvil, I got some scoreboard triggers working for my server. All I need to figure out now is how to make it so the scoreboard triggers teleport you. Inside a repeating command block I have:

```
tp @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=2,score_cmdTrigger=2] ~ ~ ~
```

and then in a chain command block that is chained to it, I have:

```
scoreboard players set @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=2,score_cmdTrigger=2] cmdTrigger 0
```

I figured out that you have to put some value in the squiggly line things at the end of the repeating one and I figured out that each one is x y and z. I just need to get the sign to tp me to the coordinates: **-614 84 -923**. How do you do this? BTW, I've tried putting those coordinates in the squiggly lines and putting in numbers that are where I am subtracted by where I need to go. Neither of these worked. They just teleported me to a random place.

Comment: First, you have not provided enough information for people to be able to answer this.  You should link your [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/324913/186522) in your question.  The two presented commands make little sense without context.  I am not fully certain what you are asking.  `tp @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=2,score_cmdTrigger=2] -614 84 -923` should work to teleport you there.  Relative coordinates are not a good idea as they are based on the players location.  To test that your coordinates are correct, directly use the tp command.  Type `/tp -614 84 -923` into chat.

Comment: Also, you have to make sure the sign you are clicking is executing the proper trigger command to set the objective score to 2 and not some other value.

Comment: If your command was `tp @a[score_cmdTrigger_min=2,score_cmdTrigger=2] -614 84 -923`, then everything worked properly.  Are you sure that's where you actually want to teleport players?

Comment: MBraedley, yes I know where I want to teleport them

Comment: I've memorized those coordinates as where the spawn point is